# How can I turn off the monitor by command line in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, monitor

It seems that commands like `xset`, `xrandr`, `busctl`, `vbetool` which are mentioned in other posts don't work for turning off the monitor in Ubuntu 18.04.

It goes off and turns back on again after a second.

What could be the problem, and what command can I use effectively?

Comment: How about with `setterm --blank 1` command??

Comment: This is what I receive : setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I use the *Screen Lock* (`Super+L`) shortcut to lock ***and*** blank the screen. Pressing `Enter` will restore the screen with a *Password* prompt.

Also, the command sequence

```
busctl --user set-property org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig PowerSaveMode i 1; \
read ; \
busctl --user set-property org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig /org/gnome/Mutter/DisplayConfig org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig PowerSaveMode i 0
```

mentioned in [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316929/display-is-not-capable-of-dpms-after-gnome-wayland-update) seems to work for me (Ubuntu 19.04 wayland). I have put a `read` statement before the second `busctl` command, so that pressing `Enter` will turn the monitor back on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, none of the commands combination with xset, xrandr, busctl, vbetool works, I just would like to know why ? what is the entity that denies to this commands the possibility to work ?

Comment: Does the Screen Lock not work also?

Comment: Yes the screen lock works (Super+L) but after a second from deep dark (off), the back light of the monitor turn back on while the monitor still remain black, that means the monitor is not turned off, its just on a stand-by mode with screen black color, I really would like to know wich process denies to turn off my screen !!!